# Selenium click on class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this html code and i try to click on the class = "btn  submit-btn".

```
<div  <div id="js-tab-a" data-tab="tab1" class="tab-content a">
        <div>
            <fieldset class="example a">
              <div class="test a">
                <input type="submit" class="btn js-submit-btn" title="Search title" value="Search">
                <input type="submit" class="btn some class" title="some title" value="some value">
              </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
     </div>

    <div id="js-tab-b" data-tab="tab2" class="tab-content b">
        <div>
            <fieldset class="example class">
              <div id="some id" class="some class">
              </div>
            </fieldset>   
            <fieldset>
              <div class="example b">
                <input type="submit" class="btn  submit-btn" value="Search" title="Search title">
                <input type="submit" class="btn some options-btn" value="some value" title="some title">
              </div>
            </fieldset>

          </form>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I want to click on (under class = example b)

```
<input type="submit" class="btn  submit-btn" value="Search" title="Search title">
```

I tried this:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@type='submit'][@value='Search']")
    WebElement submit;
    submit.click
```

and this:

```
 @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@type='submit'][@class='btn submit-btn']")
    WebElement submit;
    submit.click
```

But the "button" cannot be clicked and don't get any error.

Comment: first option should work, except it should be `Search` instead of `Suchen`, e.g. `//input[@type='submit' and @value='Search']`. Second has some classes that are not in element you posted. SO shortly: please fix your question to either show correct html, or fix your code to match html.

Comment: It looks like there is a chance there are more buttons here, possibly hidden that your current approach might be trying to click. I would probably try `"//div[@class='example b']/input[@type='submit'][@value='Search']`, or since I prefer css selectors... `div.example.b > input[type='submit'][value='Search']`. Also, as noted above you have some incorrect values that don't match.

Comment: Yes you are right. It should be:

`@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@type='submit'][@class='btn  submit-btn']")`

`@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@type='submit'][@value='Search']")`

But it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

To clear up a certain fact we can't click on the **`class = "btn submit-btn"`**. It's the **`WebElement`** which can contain **`class = "btn submit-btn"`** as one of the attribute and invoke the **`click()`** method. So we can click on the **`WebElement`** with the attribute **`class = "btn submit-btn"`**

Now, if you want to click on the **`WebElement`** under class = example b with the attribute **`class = "btn submit-btn"`** you can use the following code block :

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='example b']/input[@class='btn submit-btn' and @value='Search' and @title='Search title']")
    WebElement submit;
    submit.click
```